# Schedule Export SQL Server records to CSV file including updates

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sapb1

I am new to this community, and this is my first question, so please excuse me if inadvertently breaking any community rules.

I need to create a functionality / schedule that will EXPORT the data ADDED or UPDATED in a SQL SERVER 2012 table after every four hours to a CSV file. My front end is SAP B1. Only tool I have got is SQL Server Management Studio.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kanu

Comment: Are you allowed to make changes to the table / add tables to the database? How does SAP B1 come into it? Are you extracting data from a SAP database?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: No, I am not allowed to make any add or update statement to the database due to the SLA with SAPB1.  Yes, I am extracting the data from a SAP B1 SQL Server db.

Comment: It's not possible to determine what record has been updated unless there is an actual 'updated' field in the table. What are you really trying to do? You are obviously trying to replicate the SAP database somewhere right? How big is the database? how many records does the biggest table have? For a database with a lot of tables, building a differential replication system gets complicated quickly. It's often simpler and easier to export the entire database. Where are your CSV's going? BTW it is much more reliable to use tab seperated as opposed to comma seperated.

Comment: No, I am not trying to replicate full database. We need to create a csv file for the new records added or old records updated in a specific table. Only certain columns need to be on that csv. That csv will then be picked by our customer web portal after every four hours and update same records on that portal. I am not concerned about how web portal will pick up csv. I just need to make sure that csv is there at a particular location, and all additions and updates are covered. The concerned table does have columns, update datetime, and updating user.

Comment: Ok well your first challenge is to find a field in that table that tells you when the record was last modified. If there isn't one then you can't identify modified records and you need to get all of them.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. The table does have a field that records last updated timestamp. So we can pull records that have timestamp after last csv download. Can be complicated process as we would need to compare all records. one by one. right from the start every time the download runs. But yes, that is the basic idea.

Comment: Does it _have_ to be completely differential? That is: does matter if a file contains a bit of info that was in a prior file? IS this differential approach required to reduce data transfer or is it required to enforce uniqueness? If each file _must not_ contain records in a propr file, then you will need SSIS to compare existing files to new files. Which is far more complicated and error prone then just running a script that exports based on a time window

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Thanks for responding. How do you suggest then we communicate to the web portal that an old record has been updated?

Comment: Basically if you run `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DateUpdate >= DATEADD(h,-4,GETDATE())` you'll get all records that were updated in the last four hours. Problem is... if your job doesn't run at exactly the right time,. or misses a four hour window, you'll miss out on records. So instead you export records updated in, say, the last 4 days. This means you are sending extra records, but it means it doesn't matter if your job doesn't run a few times. That's why I asked whether it mattered if you sent more records. If it doesn't matter then you can include some "insurance" by including more records

Comment: Good point @Nick.McDermaid. I will include this in my logic. There is no harm in updating even unchanged records. I believe there will be around 50 records every day at max, including updates. Do you reckon I can still use BCP or something similar to run on SQL Server Agent?

Comment: You can definitely use BCP under SQL Agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new column name "exported" in that table with a default value 0.

Make a SSIS (**SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICES**) job/script that will export only those records with 0 on exported and after a successful export same script it will **update** exported to 1 for the exported rows.

For update you should also make a trigger of type "**instead of update**" linked to that table which will set exported to 0 if a column (**other than exported!**) is updated.

Set the SSIS job schedule to 4 hours and you're good to go :)

I think SSIS is a much better solution because:

1. You need a job to run at a schedule of 4 hours interval and also make an update after 
   that on exported column.
2. SSIS is pretty easy to use it has a visual interface where you can
   drag&drop objects like sql scripts and so on and
3. With SSIS is super easy to export in .csv , xls or even another database like Oracle, Mysql and so on.

[image: New SSIS project ion Microsft Visula Studio]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Radu. Have never worked with SSIS before. Is there any simpler way ... like schedule a query output to CSV file on SSMS using SQL Server Agent?

Comment: I think SSIS is a much better solution because: 
1. You need a job to run at a schedule of 4 hours interval and make an update after that on exported column.
2. SSIS is pretty easy to use it has a visual interface where you can drag&drop  objects like sql scripts and so on and 
3. With SSIS is super easy to export in .csv , xls or even another database likle Oracle, Mysql and so on.
If you find my answer useful you can mark as the answer of your qustion (the check mark below the answer) :)

Comment: @Kanu If SSIS is too complicated, you can try BCP

Comment: @Radu - Thanks. How to start working on SSIS; is it part of SSMS?

Comment: Which version SQL do you use?
On SQL 2012 I make a new project in Microsoft Visual Studio of type SSIS.

Comment: @Pred: Seems like I have been living under a rock; please advise what is BCP?

Comment: @Radu - I do not use/have Visual Studio. Only tool I have got is SSMS for SQL Server 2012. :(

Comment: It comes with SQL Server is a Microsft Visual Studio SHELL

Comment: Of course you must install them from the sql kit, SSIS and dev tools.

Comment: @Radu - Thanks, but I only have access SSMS. Can anything be done using that?

Comment: Yes, you can make a job for SQL Server Agent.
That job must use  BCP.
Also you cvan make the trigger from SSMS.

Comment: @Radu: If I am using below query and file path is: C:\Cert\Today.csv then how can I best use bcp?                                                             SELECT [insID], [customer], [custmrName], [contactCod], [directCsmr], [drctCsmNam], [manufSN], [internalSN], [itemCode], [itemName], [itemGroup], [manufDate], [delivery], [objType], [logInstanc], [userSign], [createDate], [userSign2], [updateDate], [U_CertDate]
FROM OINS
WHERE [updateDate] >= GETDATE()-1